# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable

Tags: php, javascript

I keep getting this error when I do this:

```
<?php
$info = $_POST['mname'];
$info = ucwords($info);

// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("javadatest") or die(mysql_error());  

// Get a specific result from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movieList
WHERE name = '$info'") or die(mysql_error());  

// get the first (and hopefully only) entry from the result
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
//echo $row['name']." ".$row['year']." ".$row['genre'];
echo "
  <script language=javascript>
  var jsvar;
  jsvar = <?php echo $row['name'], $row['year'], $row['genre'];?>
  function buy() {
    window.location = \"https://www.paypal.com\";   
    alert(\"Thanks for shopping at Movie Store\");     
  }
  var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width = 300, height = 300);
  myWindow.document.write(jsvar);
  myWindow.document.write('<body>'); 

  myWindow.document.write('<input type="button" value="Buy" onclick=/"buy()/">');

  myWindow.document.write('</body>');

 //myWindow.buy = buy;
 </script>
";
?>
```

I'm trying to use javascript in a php file by putting my javascript code in my echo statement. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$_POST['mname'] = "or 1=1"`. Boom!

Comment: I like the rep points for the similar questions in the right column

Comment: @elclanrs now they can see all the movies xD

Comment: Please post the full error and indicate which line it refers to you have a syntax error somewhere

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to write this line

```
jsvar = <?php echo $row['name'], $row['year'], $row['genre'];?>
```

just use

```
jsvar = {$row['name']} {$row['year']} {$row['genre']};
```

because you are already in PHP.

Also

**Replace**

```
myWindow.document.write('<input type="button" value="Buy" onclick=/"buy()/">');
```

**with**

```
myWindow.document.write('<input type=\"button\" value=\"Buy\" onclick=\"buy()\">');
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure whatever `jsvar = {$row['name']} {$row['year']} {$row['genre']};` is going to cause a js error.

Answer (score 0):

```
myWindow.document.write('<input type="button" value="Buy" onclick=/"buy()/">');
```

should be

```
myWindow.document.write(\"<input type='button' value='Buy' onclick='buy()'>\");
```

Comment: and see @Dipesh Parmar's answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table 
    //echo $row['name']." ".$row['year']." ".$row['genre'];
    ?>
      <script language=javascript>
      var jsvar;
      jsvar = <?php echo json_encode($row['name']), json_encode($row['year']), json_encode($row['genre']);?>
      function buy() {
        window.location = \"https://www.paypal.com\";   
        alert(\"Thanks for shopping at Movie Store\");     
      }
...
</script>
```