# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier or variable or number

Tags: php, html, parse-error

I got this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\AddMessage.php on line 83

and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Here's my code:

```
<?php   
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
        mysql_select_db("tHofbrouwerijke") or die(mysql_error());

        $name = $_FILES["ImgBericht"]["name"];
        $newnameBericht = "ImgBericht_" . $name;
        $type = $_FILES["ImgBericht"]["type"];
        $size = $_FILES["ImgBericht"]["size"];
        $temp = $_FILES["ImgBericht"]["tmp_name"];
        $error = $_FILES["ImgBericht"]["error"];
        move_uploaded_file($temp,"Uploaded/".$newnameBericht);

        echo $newnameBericht;
        $strSQL = "INSERT INTO nieuws(Naam, Message, date,NaamAfbBericht) VALUES('".$_POST['Titel']."','".$_POST['Bericht']."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."','".$newnameBericht."')"; 
        mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error());

        $ourFileName = $_POST['Titel'].".php";
        $NewMessageFile = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        $NewHTML = 
        "<html>
          <head>
            <title>
            t Hofbrouwerijke 
            </title>
            <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style/style.css' />
            <script type='text/javascript' src='Js/LatestJQuery.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='Js/JScript.js'></script>
          </head>
          <body>
           <script>(function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
              js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1';
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

            <h1>'t Hofbrouwerijke </h1>

            <h2> Bericht </h2>

            <ul class='outerlist'> 
                <li><a href='Default.php'>Home </a></li>
                <li><a href='Ontstaan.php'>Ontstaan </a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Winkel</a>
                    <div id ='winkel'>
                    <ul class='innerlist'>
                        <li><a href='Bieren.php'> Bieren </a></li>
                        <li><a href='Geschenkverpakkingen.html'> Geschenkverpakkingen </a></li>
                        <li><a href='Merchandise.html'> Merchandise </a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'>Verkooppunten</a>
                    <div id='verkooppunten'>
                    <ul class='innerlist'>
                        <li><a href='Cafes.php'> Caf&eacute;s </a></li>
                        <li><a href='Drankenhandelaars.php'> Drankenhandelaars </a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href='EigenKweek.php'>E&eacute;ndagsbrouwer </a></li>
                <li><a href='Contact.html'>Contact </a></li>
                <li><div class='fb-like' data-href='https://www.facebook.com/pages/t-Hofbrouwerijke/173136023627?fref=ts' data-width='240px' data-layout='standard' data-action='like' data-show-faces='true' data-share='true'></div><br></li>
            </ul>
            <p>
                <table border='1'>
                    <tr><td>
                        <table border='1' class='image'>
                            <tr><td>
                                <img class='nieuws' src=\"Uploaded/".$newnameBericht."\" width=\"150px\">
                            </td></tr>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <table border='1' class='news'>
                            <?php
                                mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die (mysql_error ());
                                mysql_select_db('thofbrouwerijke') or die(mysql_error());
                                $strSQL = 'SELECT * FROM nieuws WHERE Naam=\"".$_POST['Bericht']."\"';
                                $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
                                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
                                    echo '<tr><td><span class=\"titel\">'. $row['Naam']. '<br /></span></td></tr>';
                                    echo '<tr><td><div class =\"message\">'.$row['Message'] . '</div><br /></td></tr>';
                                    echo '<tr><td><span class=\"datum\"> gepost op '.$row['date'].'</span></td></tr></td>';}
                            ?>
                        </table>
                    </td></tr>
                </table>
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>";

    fwrite($NewMessageFile, $NewHTML);
    fclose($NewMessageFile);

    header('Location: ModNieuws.php');
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T\_ENCAPSED\_AND\_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T\_STRING) or variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916552/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-encapsed-and-whitespace-expecting)

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_error()` not `mysql_error ()`

```
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
```

and u are using php tags inside `<<html`.its not a good practice. dont append it to the html.

append the formed table to the current using html variable.

Comment: Good find but it may be a typo.